# Shiro annotation on OSGI

Tags: java, osgi, shiro, apache-karaf

I run an OSGI application on Karaf 4.0.4.
This application is not a web application.

I configured Apache Shiro in order to login using a custom `SecurityRealm` that use the credentials stored in an SQL database.  The `SecurityManager`and the realm are configured using Blueprint
This part works fine.

I want to use annotations like:

```
@RequiresPermissions("doSomething")
@RequiresRoles("admin")
public void myMethodToDoSomething() {
    ...
}
```

Those annoations are never evaluated. (my security realm `protected AuthorizationInfo doGetAuthorizationInfo(PrincipalCollection principals)` method is never called.

After reading some Shiro documentation, I understand it doesn't work because I don't have the required interceptor as it's defined in the Shiro Spring turorial:

```
<!-- Enable Shiro Annotations for Spring-configured beans.  Only run after -->
<!-- the lifecycleBeanProcessor has run: -->
<bean class="org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.DefaultAdvisorAutoProxyCreator" depends-on="lifecycleBeanPostProcessor"/>
<bean class="org.apache.shiro.spring.security.interceptor.AuthorizationAttributeSourceAdvisor">
<property name="securityManager" ref="securityManager"/>
```

But as I'm not using spring in my application, those lines won't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a blueprint namespace module. This can then hook into the blueprint beans to install an interceptor. As an example see the [blueprint-authz module](https://github.com/apache/aries/tree/trunk/blueprint/blueprint-authz).

Comment: How do I install such kind of module? Like a regular one?

Comment: Yes. It is just a bundle.

Comment: This is how your blueprint file should look like: https://github.com/apache/aries/blob/trunk/blueprint/blueprint-itests/src/test/resources/authz.xml

Comment: I tried to adpat your code to shiro. It almost works, the interceptor is created but when I run the `SecurityAnotationParser# isSecuredEl` method, my method (annotated with `@RequiresPermissions("test")`) always return false as it considers my method to have no annotation. It looks like the annotation is not retained whereas it should be as it's a runtime annotation. Any idea how to solve this issue?

Comment: In OSGi annotations are treated as kind of optional. If you have a bundle that exports the annotation package then the annotation is visible. So you will have to install the shiro bundle that exports this annotation org.apache.shiro.authz.annotation. You also have to make sure that your user code has an Import-Package statement for it.

Comment: Oh .. the proxy can also be a reason.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I forgot to add the import-package... One last issue I have since that a bean is correctly seen by the interceptor, I fetch this bean using its service reference `context.getService(myRef)`. Wwhen I used to do `getClass()` on this object, I got the correct class, now I got a `Proxy...` type.  As I need to use reflection on this bean class, how can I retrieve the correct object type?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123557/discussion-between-christian-schneider-and-jhamon).

Comment: @robin yes, there were more explanations on how to do it in the chat but it got deleted by now and I don't have access to the code anymore

Comment: @jhamon can you please check the code in my friends git repo https://github.com/vineethvnair0/Karaf/tree/master/shiro-rest-auth and commet how to accomplish this?

Comment: @ChristianSchneider Do you have a working example or tutorial for a integrating shiro in osgi application ?